# Java fx gluon mobile

Tags: ios, gradle, javafx, gluon

I try to launch Gradle task `createIpa` from my project but I have this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':createIpa'.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Command '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -o /Users/wstechsrl/Desktop/workspace_fx/wstech/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/thumbv7/wstech -arch armv7 -Wl,-filelist,/Users/wstechsrl/Desktop/workspace_fx/wstech/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/thumbv7/objects0 -L /Users/wstechsrl/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.robovm/robovm-dist/1.8.0/7793b612873829ad0b98f82650b49bfc16b51818/unpacked/robovm-1.8.0/lib/vm/ios/thumbv7 -ObjC -exported_symbols_list /Users/wstechsrl/Desktop/workspace_fx/wstech/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/thumbv7/exported_symbols -Wl,-no_implicit_dylibs -Wl,-dead_strip -fPIC -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk -lrobovm-bc -force_load /Users/wstechsrl/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.robovm/robovm-dist/1.8.0/7793b612873829ad0b98f82650b49bfc16b51818/unpacked/robovm-1.8.0/lib/vm/ios/thumbv7/librobovm-rt.a -lrobovm-core -lgc -lpthread -ldl -lm -lz -liconv -lsqlite3 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreText -framework ImageIO -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreMedia -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework MediaPlayer -force_load /Users/wstechsrl/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.7/2cc4c327c402343a26340cb0b9397c7c38a717fb/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libglass.a -force_load /Users/wstechsrl/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.7/2cc4c327c402343a26340cb0b9397c7c38a717fb/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libjavafx_font.a -force_load /Users/wstechsrl/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.7/2cc4c327c402343a26340cb0b9397c7c38a717fb/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libjavafx_iio.a -force_load /Users/wstechsrl/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.7/2cc4c327c402343a26340cb0b9397c7c38a717fb/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libjavafx_ios_webnode.a -force_load /Users/wstechsrl/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.7/2cc4c327c402343a26340cb0b9397c7c38a717fb/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libprism_common.a -force_load /Users/wstechsrl/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.7/2cc4c327c402343a26340cb0b9397c7c38a717fb/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libprism_es2.a -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks' failed (Exit value: 1)
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle` script? Are you targeting iOS 10? Have you tried it before?

Answer (score 0):

It has probably nothing to do with Gradle.

Run the same command outside Gradle to see if you can reproduce the error and see in more detail what went wrong.

Comment: thanks for you reply! How can I reproduce outside? Sorry but I'm new in javafx.

Comment: copy the text within '' and run in a terminal window

Comment: If I add robovm plugin in gradle I receive an other error:  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'robovm']
   > Cannot add task ':launchIPhoneSimulator' as a task with that name already exists.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Answer (score 0):

The Gluon Plugin creates a `build.gradle` file, with some dependencies. For iOS 10 to work, you should update it with the latest version of the jfxmobile plugin:

Change this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.8'
    }
}
```

to this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.9'
    }
}
```

Then launch the task again (either `createIpa` or `launchIOSDevice`), and it should work.

Otherwise, provide more information so we can check what could be the possible issue.